# Accessing value of local variable for an instance variable in java

Tags: java, variables, instance, local

I looked this up but didn't find much. Here's the code:

```
    public class Core {
        int amount = 0;
        public void startup(int Items) {
            int x = 0;
            System.out.println("Welcome Back,");
            while(x < amount) {
                amount++;
                x++;
            }
        }
        agendaitem[] item = new agendaitem[150];
        public void instantiate(String name, String status, String comments,int i) {
            item[i] = new agendaitem();
            item[i].name = name;
            item[i].complete = status;
            item[i].comments = comments;
        }
        public void error(String reason) {
            System.out.println("Error"+reason);
        }
        public void setitem(String input) throws Exception {
            Interface interf = new Interface();
            System.out.println(amount);
            int x = 0;
            while(x < amount) {
                interf.inputb(item[amount].name);
                break;
            }
        }
        public void setstatus() {

        }
        public void rename() {

        }
        public void delete() {

        }
    }
```

Basically I need to set the value of the variable amount so that it is the same as the value of Items from the method startup. Then i need to access amount from the method setitem. But for whatever reason, setitem sees amount as 0, even after i have set the value to 2 by running startup. Any advice? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you could be looking for is to make "amount" a static variable in your Core class. This would involve declaring it as follows:

```
static int amount = 0;
```

See here for info : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop inside `startup`, you're incrementing both `x` and `amount`.  So if `x < amount`, then it will always be the case that `x < amount` - at least until `amount` reaches `MAXINT`.

I strongly recommend learning to use the debugger.  You would have found this error immediately.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(x < amount)
```

will return `false`, since both `x` and `amount` are 0 at the beginning, so `amount` will always keep 0 value. Why not just doing

```
amount = items
```

?

Your `startup` method would look like this.-

```
public void startup(int Items) {
    amount = Items;
}
```

By the way, following java naming conventions, `Items` should be called `items`, camelCase.

Comment: I had it like that originally, but it didn't work so tried just incrementing amount until was equal to items

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Are you accidentally creating more than one instance of `Core` class?